# operator<< overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

I didn't find any thing that could help me in this subject...
I'm trying to over load the `<< operator`, this is my code:

```
 ostream& Complex::operator<<(ostream& out,const Complex& b){
    out<<"("<<b.x<<","<<b.y<<")";
    return out;
}
```

this is the declaration in the H file:

```
 ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const Complex& b);
```

I get this error:
    `error: std::ostream& Complex::operator<<(std::ostream&, const Complex&) must take exactly one argument`

what and why I'm doing wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

your `operator <<` should be *free* function, not `Complex` class member in your case.

If you did your `operator <<` class member, it actually should take one parameter, which should be `stream`. But then you won't be able to write like

```
std::cout << complex_number;
```

but

```
complex_number << std::cout;
```

which is equivalent to

```
complex_number. operator << (std::cout);
```

It is not common practice, as you can note, that is why `operator <<` usually defined as free function.

Comment: and that free function would usually be a `friend` of your object.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Complex
{
    int a, b;
public:
    Complex(int m, int d)
    {
        a = m; b = d;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Complex& complex);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Complex& complex)
{
    os << complex.a << '+' << complex.b << 'i';
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Complex complex(5, 6);
    cout << complex;
}
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2019)

Comment: It cannot be both a friend and a member at the same time.

Comment: @BoPersson Rewrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, the streaming overloads need to to be free functions, defined outside of your class.

Personally, I prefer to stay away from `friend`ship and redirect to a public member function instead:

```
class Complex
{
public:
   std::ostream& output(std::ostream& s) const;
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& s, const Complex& c)
{
   return c.output(s);
}
```